# How to stop Powerpoint opening in Storyboarding tab

Tags: powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I have several powerpoint presentations that when I open them (using Powerpoint 2010) the Storyboarding tab is always selected, and the Storyboarding pane is opened on the left-hand side. I close the pane, select the Home tab and Save, but next time I open the presentation it goes back to the Storyboarding again. I don't (have never) used Storyboarding, and want to stop this behaviour as it is a pain. Does anyone know how to make it forget whatever it has stored to say to open in Storyboarding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat of a hammer to crack I nut I feel, but I found one solution to my problem. Would appreciate hearing if there are other less restrictive solutions.

I went into File->Options, to the Add-ins section. I could see an Active Application Add-in called "Team Foundation Add-in".

I pressed "Go" to Manage "COM Add-ins", the type of this add-in.

[image: PowerPoint Add-ins panel]

This allowed me to unselect the add-in from the list. I didn't say "Remove...", I just unchecked it from the list.

[image]

Now my Storyboarding tab is gone and so the storyboarding pane isn't opened each time I load a powerpoint file.

It hasn't solved the problem should I ever actually want to use storyboarding, but for now it's better. However, would be interested to hear any less invasive solutions to my problem.